# What is the "Update for Meteor client-side source files is not available" message in webstorm?

Tags: google-chrome, meteor, webstorm

Trying to run/debug a meteor JS app with the new webstorm 9 (with meteor support)
I'm following this tutorial :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeqkGF3Z7rU

If I click on run, chrome is launched and my app is running. But I get this message on the event log :
Update for Meteor client-side source files is not available

And if I change something in a file (js, css or html) nothing is changing on my app on chrome. I have to manually stop and run again to see my changes.

Seems to work on the video though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When WebStorm runs Meteor it uses the -once which disables Meteor’s auto reload feature. The reason for this is that the way it currently works is incompatible with WebStorms autosave option.

Taken from
http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/09/meteor-support-in-webstorm-9/